# Allow certain ports only on one subdomain

Tags: iptables, nginx

I have multiple domains and subdomains, and I have a serivce on a port, that I'd like to setup so that it's accessible only on one certain subdomain. So for example `foo.bar:9999` works, but `bar:9999`, `baz:9999`, and `foo.baz:9999` doesn't.

How do I achieve it? I'm not able to find anything. I'm using nginx if there is a way to do it via it.

Comment: What protocol are you using? Is it `http(s)`? Is Nginx listening on port 9999, or are you thinking of deploying it as a reverse proxy? Does [this help](https://superuser.com/questions/1311050/nginx-serves-site-even-if-server-name-does-not-match).

Comment: Yes, it's https. Nginx itself isn't listening on 9999. I could use a reverse proxy and disallow the port  9999 at all on the firewall, but this doesn't work with one application - I cannot update it and it expects traffic to arrive at `/`, and as I'm running multiple instances at one subdomain, I setup the proxy such as `/app1` goes to 9999, `/app2` goes to 9998, and so on. I tried using `rewrite` but failed to get it to work, so I thought about the approach with ports. I want the applications to not be reachable over other domain than `foo.bar`. Not sure what the easiest way is.